# Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined - Javascript Error

Tags: c#, javascript

In my user control, there is a GridView.
When I check checkbox in the header of the GridView, I want to select all checkboxs.
**My user control can be use more than once in a page.**
So I try like this.

My GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEach" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            .
            .
```

This is my C# codes

```
CheckBox chkAll = gvAttachment.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("chkHeader") as CheckBox;
     if (chkAll != null)
     {
           chkAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelectAllChkBox('" + chkAll.ClientID + "','" + GridView.ClientID + "');");
     }
```

This is my javascript

```
function SelectAllChkBox(value , grid) {
    for (var i = 1; i < grid.all.length; i++) {
        grid.all[i].checked = value.checked;
    }
}
```

But I got this error.

```
Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined
```

What is wrong with my Code ?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter grid is the id (a string) of the grid view which means you don't have an "all". length works on the "grid" though. You are not passing an object from c#.

You'll need to find all the check boxes client-side and set checked based on a true or false value.

Comment: I'd recommend using a library like jQuery to simplify the task: `$(grid).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);`

Comment: This one is OK for me. But unfortunately, I can't use it.

`function SellectAllChkBox(value) { var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvAttachment.ClientID%>"); for (var i = 1; i < grid.all.length; i++) { grid.all[i].checked = value.checked; } }`

Comment: Explain some more... why can't you do that?

Comment: My user control can be use twice on a page.
So if I use like it, the 2nd control ID overwrite the first control ID ( I think ). So whichever header checkbox I click, only the second gridview works. It ignores the gridview on my first control.

Comment: yeah, that's what you wrote.... leave the gridid as a parameter to the function and call var grid = document.getElementById(gridid);

Comment: I tried like this. But same error.
`function SelectAllChkBox(value , grid) {
        var n = document.getElementById(grid);

        for (var i = 1; i < n.all.length; i++) {
            n.all[i].checked = value.checked;
        }
    }`

Comment: Sry, not the same error, I can't click on the checkbox in the header row.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you get an object back from getElementById, make sure there is an all, make sure n.all[i] is a check box. This is normal development stuff you should be able to deal with. Debug the client-side code and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

An array starts from 0:

```
function SelectAllChkBox(value , grid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.all.length; i++) {
        grid.all[i].checked = value.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: What i think is that there is no 'all' property at all but i don't know the object you are using. Try to find out if there is an 'all' property.

Comment: What i think is that there is no 'all' property at all but i don't know the object you are using. Try to find out if there is an 'all' property. Use Firebug to browse the DOM and to debug your code.

Comment: When I try like that , it's OK.



`function SellectAllChkBox(value) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvAttachment.ClientID%>");

        for (var i = 1; i < grid.all.length; i++) {
            grid.all[i].checked = value.checked;
        }

    }`

Comment: @Erwinus, from the code provided you see it's a string type. It has no all. He'll need to do document.getElementById(...) from the grid parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
function SelectAllChkBox(value , grid) {
    var n = document.getElementById("grid").rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        grid.all[i].checked = value.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete. Will still fail inside the for-loop.